# Пытаюсь вывести введённую матрицу

Tags: c, матрицы, printf

На выходе получается не то что я ожидаю.
Я еще новичок, и не могу понять в чем проблема.
Заранее спасибо)

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printm(int **matrix, int n, int m) {
    int end = n - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == end) {printf("\\");} else {
        i == 0 ? printf("/") : printf("|");}
        for (int j = 0; j < m; m++) 
        printf(" %d ", matrix[i][j]);
        if (i == end) {printf("/");} else {
        i == 0 ? printf("\\\n") : printf("|\n");}
    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    int n, m;
    printf("введите размер матрицы:\n");
    printf("  n: "); scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("  m: "); scanf("%d", &m);
    int **matrix = (int**) calloc (n, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*) calloc (m, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        }
    }

    printm(matrix, n, m);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что вы ожидаете получить на выходе? Дополните вопрос примером требуемого ввода и вывода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое - всегда пишите нормально форматированный код. В нем куда легче разобраться.

Ваша главная ошибка -

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; m++)
```

Сами подумайте - остановится ли когда-нибудь такой цикл? Что надо увеличивать - счетчик или предельное значение?

Ну и для выравнивания следует указать ширину вывода чисел. У вас максимальное значение - 100, значит, ширины 3 должно хватить.

```
void printm(int **matrix, int n, int m)
{
    int end = n - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == end)
        {
            printf("\\");
        }
        else
        {
            i == 0 ? printf("/") : printf("|");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf(" %3d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        if (i == end)
        {
            printf("/");
        }
        else
        {
            i == 0 ? printf("\\\n") : printf("|\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь это то, что вы хотели?